# How to extract text from an HTML file in Google Colab

Tags: python, html, google-colaboratory

I wrote some html files. I want to use this in colab as data (text data). For example, I want to use text which is in `<h1> "text "</h1>`, also I  need to extract the whole class and this kind of staff. Can you tell me how to upload HTML file in google colab and after extract some text from here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can render the HTML using the `IPython.display.HTML` helper.

Then, use the `eval_js` helper in `google.colab.output` to grab the text in the rendered HTML.

Here's the [full example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vEZigVViLs7-xJ1V_BTGm44wX8KBJaY1?usp=sharing):

[image]

Replicating the key code here:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
from google.colab import output

# Render the HTML.
display(HTML(open('example.html').read()))

html_text = output.eval_js('document.body.innerText')
```

To upload local files, you can use the left hand file browser panel like so:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is for sure a solution. Do you know how to upload file form comp, without copy HTML code in python?

Comment: Sure, I added some pointers for file upload in an edit.

Comment: One last question, do you know how to extract an unordered list? I have a class name for this unlist